# Handling select box values using HTML jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a code like this.

HTML:

```
    <select id="from_value">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <select id="to_value">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
```

JQuery:

```
    $("#from_value").change(function () {
    var val = +this.value;
    $("#to_value option").hide();
    $("#to_value option:gt(" + val + "),#to_value option:eq(" + val + ")").show();
    $("#to_value").val(val);
    });
```

The code is shared in jsfiddle for easy editing. http://jsfiddle.net/fuub1wrd/1/

When the from value is changed, the to value is getting changed based on from_value event.

Now, what I'm trying to do is.

If the `from_value` is `5`, then the `to_value` should display `5,6,7,8` only (only four values from the selected value)

In other words, display only four values with respect to the from_value.
If `from_value` is `6`, then in `to_values` i should be able to see only `6,7,8,9`

How can I achieve that? I know this is bit easy, but still, I'm sitting with my code.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Please do not "tag-spam".  Your question has nothing to do with [tag:php] or the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("#from_value").change(function () {
    var val = +this.value;
    $("#to_value option")
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
        return ($(this).val() >= val && $(this).val() < val + 4);
    })
    .show();
    $("#to_value").val(val);
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fuub1wrd/4/**

It hides all the options and then uses the `filter()` function in order to identify the options you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select id="from_value">
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select id="to_value">
     <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Jquery :

```
$("#from_value").change(function () {
    var val = +this.value;
    $("#to_value option").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#to_value option:lt(" + val + ")").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuub1wrd/5/)

Comment: please read my question again and help me out. this is not working as expected. thanks anyway.